# Слово с -не-

Tags: частица-не, грамматика

Как написать слово с -не-: «явно не завершенные рассуждения»?

Answer (score 1):

От смысла зависит. Хотелось бы всю фразу видеть.
Скорее всего -  слитно, незавершенность здесь новое качество, как в "незавершенная рукопись".  
Но если смысл в отрицании завершенности, то может быть и раздельно.
И ещё есть вариант "явно не завершенные, но завершенные неявно". Тогда тоже логично раздельное написание.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что причастие здесь употреблено в значении прилагательного (незавершенность как признак), а в таких случаях наличие пояснительных слов не влияет на раздельное написание. (Розенталь и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, §70, примечание 3). Думаю, надо писать слитно.

Comment: *Похоже*, но не более. 
Без контекста наверняка утверждать нельзя.  
Да и со значением слова "явно" уверенности нет. Если это антоним к тайно, скрыто, то креако сомневаюсь, что тут прилагательное как признак.